# Confirming transactions on my own blockchain

Tags: go-ethereum, mist, private-blockchain

I have gone through [this](https://codeburst.io/build-your-first-ethereum-smart-contract-with-solidity-tutorial-94171d6b1c4b) guide to create my own Ethereum smart contract on my own private network. I have created my own network, I have a smart contract code ready, I have Mist installed to deploy the contract, but the problem is - contract is stuck in "creating contract" mode (with 0/12 confirmations).

Now, i'm the only miner, of course, and I have been mining for the last 2 hours on the network (have mined 5000 ethers on the same account that deployed the contract), but I haven't confirmed the smart contract and i can't grasp why.

I have created two contracts, one with default amount of gas and the second with maximum amount of gas, both are still being confirmed with 0 confirmations so far.

So, my questions are -

1) How to confirm the smart contract and why is it not being confirmed? One of the reasons I think might be that when I start Mist, it says 1000 blocks out of 711000 are synced. But in the guide it said that when we are on our own network, we don't have to care about syncing anymore.....

2) Is more of an additional question - how can I connect my second computer to the private network to mine too? Is it enough to transfer the genesis.json and chaindata files and just connect on the other computer with "geth --datadir=./chaindata/" and "geth attach ...." commands?

Thanks

Comment: Are you connected to the correct network? 711,000 are lots of blocks for a private blockchain. To send transactions you need to be synced.

Comment: I should be connected to the correct network, because i've been mining Ether's succesfully. And I don't understand the 711000 blocks either, but do they matter when I have my own network?

Comment: No problem with that number. If you generate one block each 15 seconds, then 711000 blocks is about 115 days. Are you running a single node? Because a single node should always be in sync, but Mist appears to be out of sync.

Comment: just a small update -> I downloaded the blockchain on another computer and did the exact same steps as before and now the computer verifies the contracts and transactions without problem. It's weird, I have heard before that sometimes when something with Ethereum doesn't work, it doesn't necessarily mean you did something wrong.